# Why is jQuery returning each character of the contents of my span element when I loop it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, I have bunch of span with an endtime class. I want to get each of the contents independently from the others.

```
<span class='endtime'>
  2011-03-29 00:01:03
</span>

<span class='endtime'>
 2011-03-31 19:20:11
</span>

<span class='endtime'>
 2011-03-28 19:00:12
</span>
```

But the problem is, when I do this:

```
var text = $('.endtime').text();
for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      $('.counter').countdown({
            until: text[i],
            format: 'HMS'
      })
}
```

The contents of the text only have 1 character? How to make it return the whole characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling `.text()` you can optionally pass in a function to execute on each item in the collection.

```
$("span.endtime").text(function(i, text){
      $('.counter').countdown({
            until: text,
            format: 'HMS'
      })
});
```

**Simple example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/dJa8S/1/).**

Comment: Doesn't that also replace the text, in this case with `undefined`?

Comment: @Kobi, as long as nothing is returned the text elements are not changed.

Comment: yes it is down.. i thought im the only one having trouble with that site!

Answer (score 2):

[`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text) returns a **string** of the first element, not all texts of all elements!

To iterate over all elements, try this:

```
$('.endtime').each(function(){
   var text = $(this).text();
   //something with text
});
```

If you really want an *array* you can also write:

```
var texts = $('.endtime')
             .map(function(){return $(this).text();})
             .get();
// texts is now an array of strings.
// rest of the code is the same.
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
var text = $('.endtime');
for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  $('.counter').countdown({
        until: text[i].text(),
        format: 'HMS'
  })
}
```